# Multipage PDF made with reportlab not indexing the information displayed

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to create a multi page PDF using a for loop. Reportlab creats the correct number of pages but dosn't seem to index the text to be displayed. The page number indexes correctly but not the data.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4


def Multipage(data):
    c = canvas.Canvas("multipage.pdf", pagesize=A4)
    w, h = A4
    page_count = len(data)
    textobject = c.beginText(10, h - 20)
    for page in range(len(data)):
        page_num = c.getPageNumber()
        page_txt = "Page %s of %s" % (page_num, page_count)
        for line in range(len(data[page])):
            textobject.textLine(data[page][line])
            print(data[page][line])
        c.drawText(textobject)
        c.drawString(w - 90, 10, page_txt)
        c.showPage()
    c.save()
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    checks = [["line one pg1", "line two pg1"],["line one pg2", "line two pg2"],["line one pg3", "line two pg3"]]
    Multipage(checks)
```